# Why -marm option still generates thumb instruction?

Tags: arm

(I am new to the ARM world. Excuse me if this is a dumb question.)

I am using below command line to generate assembly code for a C file.

The cpu is `arm926ej-s`, which is `ARMv5 architecture`.

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -mcpu=arm926ej-s -mthumb -S t.c -o t_thumb.S
arm-none-eabi-gcc -mcpu=arm926ej-s -marm -S t.c -o t_arm.S
```

I am expecting the `-marm` and `-mthumb` options would generate different function prologues. But they give **similar** results:

for -marm:

```
@ args = 0, pretend = 0, frame = 72
@ frame_needed = 1, uses_anonymous_args = 0
push    {fp, lr} @<========== push is used instead of stmfd
add fp, sp, #4
sub sp, sp, #72
bl  uart_init
```

for -mthumb:

```
@ args = 0, pretend = 0, frame = 72
@ frame_needed = 1, uses_anonymous_args = 0
push    {r7, lr} @<========== push is used as expected
sub sp, sp, #72
add r7, sp, #0
bl  uart_init
```

So they both use the `push` instruction. But as I checked the ARMv5 arch spec, the `push` instruction **only** belongs to the `Thumb` instruction set. I was expecting `stmfd` for the `-marm` option.

Why is `push` chosen instead?

How can I generate **pure** ARM instructions?

### ADD 1 - 5:21 PM 12/18/2019

Below is the disassembly of the `.o` file:

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -mcpu=arm926ej-s -marm -g -c t.c -o build/t_arm.o
arm-none-eabi-objdump.exe -d build/t_arm.o > t_arm.dism
```

The disassembly:

```
000002a0 <main>:
 2a0:   e92d4800    push    {fp, lr} <=============== push is used!
 2a4:   e28db004    add fp, sp, #4
 2a8:   e24dd048    sub sp, sp, #72 ; 0x48
 2ac:   ebfffffe    bl  0 <uart_init>
 2b0:   e59f3168    ldr r3, [pc, #360]  ; 420 <main+0x180>
 2b4:   e50b300c    str r3, [fp, #-12]
 2b8:   e59f1164    ldr r1, [pc, #356]  ; 424 <main+0x184>
 2bc:   e51b000c    ldr r0, [fp, #-12]
```

### ADD 2 - 5:34 PM 12/18/2019

Thanks to **@Erlkoenig**.

I just tried to disassemble a `-mthumb` binary:

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -mcpu=arm926ej-s -mthumb -g -c t.c -o build/t_thumb.o
arm-none-eabi-objdump.exe -d build/t_thumb.o > t_thumb.dism
```

A totally different `thumb` disassembly is shown:

```
00000170 <main>:
 170:   b580        push    {r7, lr} <====== though still push is shown, but the encoding is different.
 172:   b092        sub sp, #72 ; 0x48
 174:   af00        add r7, sp, #0
 176:   f7ff fffe   bl  0 <uart_init>
 17a:   4b3c        ldr r3, [pc, #240]  ; (26c <main+0xfc>)
 17c:   643b        str r3, [r7, #64]   ; 0x40
 17e:   4a3c        ldr r2, [pc, #240]  ; (270 <main+0x100>)
 180:   6c3b        ldr r3, [r7, #64]   ; 0x40
```

Comment: What happens if you compile directly (`-c` instead of `-S`) and disassemble the result (`arm-none-eabi-objdump -d t_arm.o`)?

Comment: @Erlkoenig I debugged the final binary built with `-marm` on qemu. It is still `push` instruction.

Comment: Can you show the disassembly from `objdump`, including the hexadecimal representation of the instructions?

Comment: @Erlkoenig Please see my ADD 1. Thanks.

Comment: This *is* a 32bit ARM instruction encoding (e92d4800). The generated `.S` file and `objdump` output just show `stmfd` as `push`, but it is actually ARM, not thumb. See p. 339 in the ARMv5 RefMan - it matches the encoding of `stm`.

Comment: Thanks. I will try to confirm the encoding of `stmfd` and `push` instructions. But if it is so, what a misleading *feature*...

Comment: The tools are using the Unified Assembly Language (ARM UAL) which uses `push` as an alias for `stmdb` on ARM code, while the ARMv5T RefMan uses the old syntax where there is no `push` for ARM.

Comment: @Erlkoenig Thanks for mentioning the `UAL`. If you consolidate your comments into an answer, I will mark it.

Comment: you are using gcc to assemble a file, use the assembler.  Second the assembly language has syntax to select the instruction set.  after the unified thing push was valid in both instruction sets its an stm instruction just the mnemonic can be push instead of stmdb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hex encoding of the raw instruction as shown by `objdump -d` indicates that this *is* a 32bit ARM ("[A32](https://developer.arm.com/architectures/instruction-sets)") instruction (0xe92d4800). The `.S` file generated by the `-S` flag to `GCC`, and the `objdump` output just use the ARM UAL (Unified Assembly Syntax), which uses `push` as an alias for `stmfd`, while the ARMv5T Architecture Reference Manual uses the old syntax, which has no `push` on A32. The instruction encoding matches the encoding of `stmdb`, for which `stmfd` is an alias. The encoding is shown on p. 339 in the ARMv5T Reference Manual.

A32 ("ARM") code can be easily recognized as all instructions are 4-byte wide and the first 4 bits are often hex `E` (which means that the condition code is `AL`, i.e. the instructions are always executed unconditionally):

```
[e]92d4800
[e]28db004
[e]24dd048
[e]bfffffe
```

This is helpful when viewing raw binaries in a hex editor. Thumb ("T32") code has many 16bit instructions, some 32bit, and no "stacks" of `E`s:

```
b580
b092
af00
f7ff fffe
```

Of course, for a raw binary, it is not directly clear which 2- and 4-byte groups belong together as instructions.